# How to wrap equations around a figure?

Tags: equations, wrapfigure, wrap

I use LaTeX for taking notes in my math classes. I find that in classes with more plots, the document becomes far too spaced out having these plots on their own seperate line each time. For my plots I insert photos of hand drawn plots. I have tried wrapping my text and equations around the figure, but I can't get the equations to wrap around the figure. This creates tons of issues when trying to compile. Is there some way to wrap equations around figures properly? Ideally I would like to have the figure be on aligned to the left of the screen and have the text/equations be to the right of the figure.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your question will be far more clear if you'd show in form of small but complete document, what you try so far. Now I can only guess, that solution may be insert math and image in two successive minipages, or insert them in table or ... ?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I would approach this by putting the equations in minipges, and setting those side by side the appropriate diagrams.  The diagrams should then be input directly with `\includegraphic`, no `figure`.

Comment: Equations are implmented by \trivlist  and wrapfug does not handle lists well.  I am fond of using paracol, although you would have to break the equation into pieces to actually wrap it **around** the picture.

Comment: The minipages worked very well to allow me to have the pictures side by side with the equations. Thank you!